# Center a button

Tags: html, css

My website is currently hosted here: https://jogh-reports-zaksheikh.c9users.io/. At the bottom a **load more** button appears and I need to center this button and make it fill the width of the last post. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#infinite-handle {
overflow: hidden;
max-width: 88%;  /* adjust as per requirement*/
margin: 20px auto; /* adjust as per requirement*/
}
```

**As per your comment the Updated Code :**

```
#infinite-handle {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

Comment: That centers it, but I also need for it to spread the full width of the page.

Comment: That's why I have commented the code. Adjust the width to 100%.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I need for the top of the button to line up with the bottom of the post. Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: Do you want the button to be positioned just under the last left block of post.? If not, please provide some more detail.

Comment: Yep, I want it immediately underneath the last post.

Comment: Please check the update answer .

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right, you problem is in your max-width for infinite-handle, you should use something like none or 90% instead of fixed value and change magin left/right to feel space. For example:

```
    margin: 20px 1%;
    width: 98%;
    max-width: none;
```